# Add submenu to context menu in Visual Studio Extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

I want to add a submenu to the context menu in Visual Studio. Similar to what resharper does:
[image: resharper submenu]

My setup is as follows:
`MyTopMenuGroup`: contains `Command1` and `MyMenuController`. The MenuController itself has again another group, which contains some other commands. Unfortunately the MenuController is not displayed.

My XAML:

```
<Groups>
  <Group guid="mypkg" id="MyTopMenuGroup" >
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_ITEMNODE" />
  </Group>
  <Group guid="mypkg" id="MySubMenuGroup">
    <Parent guid="mypkg" id="MyMenuController" />
  </Group>
</Groups>

<Menus>
  <Menu guid="mypkg" id="MyMenuController" type="MenuController">
    <Parent guid="mypkg" id="MyTopMenuGroup" />
  </Menu>
</Menus>

<Buttons>
  <Button guid="mypkg" id="Command1" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="mypkg" id="MyTopMenuGroup" />
  </Button>
  <Button guid="mypkg" id="Command2" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="mypkg" id="MyMenuController" />
  </Button>
  <Button guid="mypkg" id="Command3" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="mypkg" id="MySubMenuGroup" />
  </Button>
  <Button guid="mypkg" id="Command4" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="mypkg" id="MySubMenuGroup" />
  </Button>
</Buttons>
```

C# which adds the buttons to the menu:

```
OleMenuCommandService commandService = this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
if (commandService != null)
{
    var menuCommandID = new CommandID(CommandSet, Command1);
    var menuItem = new MenuCommand(this.MenuItemCallback, menuCommandID);
    commandService.AddCommand(menuItem);

    //etc, do this for all 4 Commands
    //no code to construct groups & menus (is this necessary?)
}
```

Command1 is displayed as "top-level" command as expected.
The other commands and the Menu is not displayed at all.

Why is the Menu not shown and how can I make it visible?

Comment: The setup was fine, a reboot fixed my problem. For others struggling with this, I've written a small introduction on how to archive this: https://blog.famoser.ch/visual-studio-extensions-commands/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XAML looks fine (I presume Buttons and Menus actually have Strings sections) and Command3/Command4 should be visible. Just make sure they have MenuItemCallbacks attached like Command1.

Comment: You were right, the setup was fine. Sometimes all you need is a reboot.